# How strict should off-topic questions be flagged as such?

Tags: discussion, scope, flagging

I flagged [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746009/integrity-of-2-files-containing-several-md5-checksums-using-md5sum-c) as off-topic.

The question absolutely does not belong on Ask Ubuntu but on Stack Overflow or similar. But the flag got declined and that's bad for my reputation (?).

It makes no sense to flag if things go this way.

So, how strict should we be when we flag questions as off-topic?

Comment: What makes you think that that is a SO question? Is not about programming...

Comment: because you may do wht the asker want to with the given tool if you to well bash scripting. And for my understanding complex bash scripting is more programming but help on how to use shell commands

Answer (score 13):

This is 100% about using a command line tool that ships with Ubuntu as part of the `coreutils` package. There aren't many tools that are more Ubuntu.

In the same way that we answer Ubuntu users' questions about Firefox and LibreOffice, this is completely on-topic. Without questions like this, there'd only be five questions left on Ask Ubuntu. And there'll be somebody who wants to close those too.

There are some topics that do make me wonder sometimes but this just isn't one of them.

Comment: `that ships with Ubuntu as part of the XYZ package` gives a lot of room. I got it an will do it that way.

Comment: That's not an exclusive inclusion. We support stuff that isn't on the CD too, I'm just making the point that `md5sum` is one of the most core applications in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

General usage of command line tools available on Ubuntu is usually on-topic here, as is shell scripting. On the other hand, I see no particular reason why that question should belong on SO; there is nothing particularly programmer-centric in it. It could belong on SU or U&L, but, by the same token, it belongs here too.